# simple html dom traversal confusion when looping

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to use the php script [simplehtmldom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) to loop over divs on a web page while scraping.

Right now I have this:

```
$url = "https://test.com/";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);

$item_list = $html->find('div.main div[id]');

foreach ($item_list as $item)
{
    echo $item->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will give me many like this (from the echo in the loop above):

```
<div id=1>
    <div>
      stuff here
    </div> 
    <div>
     <span class="title">name</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=2>
    <div>
      stuff here
    </div> 
    <div>
     <span class="title">name 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is loop over the span with class=title, but no matter what I can't seem to quite get the right selector. Could someone help me out?

Comment: You need to post `$url` html content

Comment: No I don't. The HTML content I'm dealing with in the loop is right there in the second code block.

Comment: You could add searching for a span with class `title` like `$item_list = $html->find('div.main div span[class=title]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the spans adding `span[class=title]` as a selector:

```
$item_list = $html->find('div.main div[id] span[class=title]');

foreach ($item_list as $item)
{
    echo $item->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```